# Elastic Search Terms query not giving result but match query is giving

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, kibana, nest, elasticsearch.net

I am using a Kibana query

```
GET /MY_INDEX_HERE/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "AccountId": 
        "bc73afda-d4f2"
      
    }
  }
}
```

and it is giving me the results, I expect. But when I use a `terms` query, it is not showing any result, although the values are same. There is no difference in any character or any case, everything is lower-case only.

My final goal is to get the result in my C# code. My query is

```
.Query(q => q.Raw(strQuery) && q.Terms(c => c.Name("by_account").Field(p => p.AccountsList).Terms(accountTerms))
```

With this query I am getting zero results, but if I comment the second query I am getting results:

```
.Query(q => q.Raw(strQuery) //&& q.Terms(c => c.Name("by_account").Field(p => p.AccountsList).Terms(accountTerms))
```

Right now my

```
strQuery ={\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"match_phrase_prefix\":{\"fullname\":\"test\"}}]}}
```

and

```
  List<string> accountTerms = new List<string>();
                accountTerms.Add("bc73afda-d4f2");
```

The `AccountId` is a `GUID` type, I cant paste the full value here, hence it's not a complete value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Troubleshooting Kibana 'terms' Query

The `terms` query is an exact match query, which means it doesn't analyze the query input or the field values before matching them.

If the `AccountId` field in your index has been mapped as a `keyword` field or a text field with the `keyword` type, then the input `bc73afda-d4f2` will be treated as a single term, and it will only match if the field value is an exact match, including case.

Check the mapping of the `AccountId`:

```bash
GET /MY_INDEX_HERE/_mapping/field/AccountId
```

If the `type` of the field is `text` or `keyword`, Adjust your query to use the exact case and value of the field.

Alternatively, you can use a `match_phrase` query instead of the `terms` query to match the exact phrase of the `AccountId` field, regardless of the case.

```bash
GET /MY_INDEX_HERE/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "AccountId": "bc73afda-d4f2"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your data is stored in a `text` field, which is an analyzed field type.

If you are using the standard analyzer, your source `bc73afda-d4f2` is transformed into the two tokens `bc73afda` and `d4f2`. Therefore, if you're querying for the term `bc73afda-d4f2` there is no token that matches .

You have different options now, depending on what you want to achieve exactly and which parts you can influence (Elasticsearch and/or C# code).

1. You could edit your second query to use `match_phrase` instead of `term`.
2. You could add your second condition to the existing `strQuery`. That would be something along the lines of:

   ```
   \"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"match_phrase_prefix\":{\"fullname\":\"test\"}},{\"match_phrase\":{\"AccountId\":\"bc73afda-d4f2\"}}]}}
   ```
3. If your mapping is a multi-type `text/keyword` field or you can make it into one (or just use a `keyword` field instead of `text`), you can query the `AccountId.keyword` field with your `terms` query. `keyword` fields are not analyzed, so the `term` query for `bc73afda-d4f2` would be a hit.
4. You could use a custom analyzer and reindex your data. But this is probably overkill/the wrong way to approach your issue.

Comment: then what should i do ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Please update your question to include sample data, the field types and an explicit question. With the information given so far, I'd say: just use a `search` query.

Comment: yes you are correct, i just tried now, if i am using bc73afda with term it is showing the value, now how can i solve this ?

Comment: .Query(q => q.Raw(strQuery) && q.Terms(c => c.Name("by_account").Field(p => p.AccountsList).Terms(accountTerms)) this is my query in c# code i want results, but i am getting zero results becuase of the account filed, but if i comment the second query then it is giving result

Comment: Again: please edit the question to add the missing information. We still do not know what the data looks like, especially what the field type is. You will have to provide the necessary information if you want people to help you.

Comment: @buddemet, i have provided, sorry for that, i am new to stackover na thats why i am like a noob

Comment: No problem, welcome to stackoverflow! It's just that the answer depends on the exact [Elasticsearch field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-types.html) and whether it is maybe a mutlifield. Could you please add the part of the mapping that describes the field `AccountId`? I am not aware of an Elasticsearch type `GUID`...

Comment: You can get your mapping with `GET /MY_INDEX_HERE/_mapping`.

Comment: Thanks! Had the same issue and your `match_phrase` method helped this elastic search newbie.